# Comparing two images - Detect egg in a nest

Tags: vb.net, image-processing

I have a webcam directly over a chicken nest. This camera takes images and uploads them to a folder on a server. I'd like to detect if an egg has been laid from this image.

I'm thinking the best method would be to compare the contrast as the egg will be much more reflective than the straw nest. (The camera has Infrared so the image is partly grey scale)

I'd like to do this in .NET if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to resize your image to a smaller size, maybe 10 x 10 pixel. This averages out any small disturbing details.

```
Const  N As Integer = 10
Dim newImage As New Bitmap(N, N)
Dim fromCamera As Image = Nothing ' Get image from camera here
Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed
    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bilinear
    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed
    gr.DrawImage(fromCamera, New Rectangle(0, 0, N, N))
End Using
```

Note: you do not need a high quality, but you need a good averaging. Maybe you will have to test different quality settings.

Since now, a pixel covers a large area of your original image, a bright pixel is very likely part of an egg. It might also be a good idea to compare the brightness of the brightest pixel to the average image brightness, since that would reduce problems due to global illumination changes.

---

**EDIT** (in response to comment):

Your code is well structured and makes sense. Here some thoughts:

Calculate the gray value from the color value with:

```
Dim grayValue = c.R * 0.3 + c.G * 0.59 + c.B * 0.11
```

... instead of comparing the three color components separately. The different weights are due to the fact, that we perceive green stronger than red and red stronger than blue. Again, we do not want a beautiful thumbnail we want a good contrast. Therefore, you might want to do some experiments here as well. May be it is sufficient to use only the red component. Dependent on lighting conditions one color component might yield a better contrast than others. I would recommend, to make the gray conversion part of the thumbnail creation and to write the thumbnails to a file or to the screen. This would allow you to play with the different settings (size of the thumbnail, resizing parameters, color to gray conversion, etc.) and to compare the (intermediate) results visually. Creating a bitmap (bmp) with the (end-)result is a very good idea.

The `Using` statement does the `Dispose()` for you. It does it even if an exception should occur before `End Using` (There is a hidden `Try Finally` involved).

Comment: http://pastie.org/2998305 What do you think of this? Any improvements? The Chickens should start laying soon so I can gather more data.